# Taking values from a Database clicking on an Item of a ListView and show them into a Dialog

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite, android-dialog

As the title, I'm trying to get values from a SQLite Database clicking on an Item of a ListView. This ListView shows every value of the database in a DESC order. After clicked on it a Dialog is supposed to appear showing a summary of that value.

this is the onItemClick method:

```
Val_List.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            int pos = position + 1;

            String[] projection2 = {
                    _ID,
                    DiabeticContract.DiabeticEntry.COLUMN_GLYCAEMIA_VALUES,
                    DiabeticContract.DiabeticEntry.COLUMN_DATES,
            };

            Cursor cursor2 = db2.query(
                    DiabeticContract.DiabeticEntry.TABLE_NAME,   // The table to query
                    projection2,            // The columns to return
                    null,                  // The columns for the WHERE clause
                    null,                  // The values for the WHERE clause
                    null,                  // Don't group the rows
                    null,                  // Don't filter by row groups
                    null);                   // The sort order

            cursor2.move(pos);

            String date, notes;
            int g_val = 0;

            g_val = cursor2.getInt(cursor2.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DiabeticContract.DiabeticEntry.COLUMN_GLYCAEMIA_VALUES));
            date = cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DiabeticContract.DiabeticEntry.COLUMN_DATES));
            //notes = cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DiabeticContract.DiabeticEntry.COLUMN_NOTES));


            customDialog(DIALOG_TITLE, date, "");
            cursor2.close();
        }

    });
```

The problem is that if i click on the first item in the listview the position is equal 1 and it takes the values in the first row of the Database, instead of the last one.

How can i solve that?

Thank you very much!

EDIT:

```
public class DiabeticCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter
{

    private ImageView check;

    public int glyc_value;
    public String glyc_date;
    public DiabeticCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c,0);
    }


    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.gly_item_list, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor)
    {
        TextView glycaemia_value = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Glyc_value);
        TextView test_date = (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.Date_time);
        check = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.check_view);

        glyc_value = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DiabeticContract.DiabeticEntry.COLUMN_GLYCAEMIA_VALUES));
        glyc_date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DiabeticContract.DiabeticEntry.COLUMN_DATES));

        checkVal(glyc_value);
        glycaemia_value.setText("Glycaemia Value : " + glyc_value + " mg/dl");
        test_date.setText("Added : " + glyc_date);

    }

    private void checkVal(int n)
    {
        if (n< 75 || n >= 125)
        {
            check.setImageResource(R.drawable.check_red);
        } else
            if (n >= 75 && n <100)
            {
                check.setImageResource(R.drawable.check_green);
            } else
                if (n >= 100 && n < 125)
                {
                    check.setImageResource(R.drawable.check_yellow);
                }
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: the display on listview method

```
private void DisplayDataValues() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        String[] projection = {
                _ID,
                DiabeticContract.DiabeticEntry.COLUMN_GLYCAEMIA_VALUES,
                DiabeticContract.DiabeticEntry.COLUMN_DATES,
                DiabeticContract.DiabeticEntry.COLUMN_NOTES,
        };

        // Perform a query on the pets table
        Cursor curs = db.query(
                DiabeticContract.DiabeticEntry.TABLE_NAME,   // The table to query
                projection,            // The columns to return
                null,                  // The columns for the WHERE clause
                null,                  // The values for the WHERE clause
                null,                  // Don't group the rows
                null,                  // Don't filter by row groups
                _ID + " DESC");                   // The sort order


        DiabeticCursorAdapter adapter = new DiabeticCursorAdapter(this, curs);

        Val_List.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

EDIT 3: this is the solution: (thanks to @Mike M.)

```
Val_List.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                int pos = position;

                curs.moveToPosition(pos);

                String date, notes;
                int g_val;

                g_val = curs.getInt(curs.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DiabeticContract.DiabeticEntry.COLUMN_GLYCAEMIA_VALUES));
                date = curs.getString(curs.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DiabeticContract.DiabeticEntry.COLUMN_DATES));
                notes = curs.getString(curs.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DiabeticContract.DiabeticEntry.COLUMN_NOTES));


                customDialog(DIALOG_TITLE, date, g_val, notes, "");
            }

        });
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you can show us how you have populated the data in ListView with Adapter

Comment: @MDDanishAnsari i just added it

Comment: You've already got a `Cursor` that you're using with the `Adapter`. You can use `moveToPosition()` on that to get the record for the clicked row. If you do need to query again - e.g., if your `Adapter`'s `Cursor` doesn't have all the info you need - then use the `id` parameter in `onItemClick()` in the query to get just the record you need, instead of pulling the entire table.

Comment: @MikeM. I didn't really understand what you mean, but one thing: if I click on the third item on a listView of 10 items, it is going to take the third row in my database. This is due to the fact that my list is in DESC order

Comment: The `position` doesn't mean anything as far as the database table is concerned, so don't try to relate them. If you use the `position`, use it with the `Cursor` you're giving to the `CursorAdapter` - i.e., `moveToPosition()` on that `Cursor`, then get the data from it. Alternatively, if you do need to query again, use the `id` to get the exact record from the table. As mentioned, `position` doesn't mean anything there.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you. So how can I do that?

Comment: From those snippets, it looks like the `Cursor` you're giving the `Adapter` already has everything you need. If that's the case, then make the `Cursor curs` a class field - e.g., `private Cursor curs;` - so you can access it anywhere in the `Activity`, and then `curs.moveToPosition(position);` in `onItemClick()`, and do the `getInt()` and `getString()` calls on that. Do be sure to remove the `Cursor` declaration from in from of `curs` where you have it now - `curs = db.query(...` - and do not close `curs` in `onItemClick()`.

Comment: @MikeM. I understood what you mean. The problem is the position that I have to pass in moveToPosition(). If I take the position of the item from the listview it will be different than the row in the Database. The tenth row will be the first in the ListView, so if I pass in curs.moveToPosition( 1 ), it will take the first row from the database

Comment: after reading and reading again your answer I got it and thank you I solved the problem. @MikeM. really thank you very much